# ASP.NET - Security Vulnerability (Cryptographic Oracles) - why html redirect for pre .NET 3.5 SP1

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-3.5

Why does the recent [ASP.NET security vurnerability](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx) specify an html error page to redirect to pre ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 but an aspx page for later versions?

Comment: RE the vote to close, I'm looking for the technical reason why so I can understand the attack. This shouldn't be open ended/unanswerable etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it does not really matters what you redirect to (html or aspx). The main point is to redirect to a page that display the same HTML regardless of the error were a 404 or 500.

Comment: I think its because the further protection is only available in .NET 3.5 SP1 so there is no need to for an aspx page.

Comment: e.g. "If you are using .NET Framework version 3.5 SP1 or 4.0, the workaround provides further protection by also helping to mitigate against potential timing analysis attacks.  The workaround uses the redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" option in the customErrors feature, and introduces a random delay in the error page.  These approaches work together to make it more difficult for an attacker to deduce the type of error that occurred on the server by measuring the time it took to receive the error."